Kids show with roly-poly ball creatures; they live in a big treehouse on a hill
There was a kids show I watched back when I was young, and I'm not sure if it's even real now since I searched everywhere and couldn't find it. It's basically a show with like little cartoony 3D creatures that can turn into like roly-poly-ish kind of balls where they can roll around. 
I remember one episode was about cheating test answers, and one episode had a skateboarding scene, except they weren't skateboarding; they were rolling. And these little creatures had, like, one solid color and some polka dots/spots of a different color. I think the main character was a pink girl, and I think one of her friends was like a goofy character who couldn't speak and just made funny noises. 
They all lived in this big treehouse, kind of on a hill, I think. That's all I remember about it. Anyone who remembers what show this might be, please tell! I've been looking for it forever, as that was my favorite show as a child, but it hasn't shown up since I was like 6–7.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't really sound very on-topic.  Were there actual fantasy or science fiction elements to this show?

..... this is Popples isn't it

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

To start with, we don't know how old you are, so we don't know when you were 6-7.

Or which country this was in.

After some checking of my dates and memory, this does appear to be Popples.  The show premiered in 2015 on Netflix, but per Wikipedia was also aired on a Discovery channel network for kids.

Fuzzy goofy critters that roll into poofy balls and zip/bounce around, check
the one that speaks gibberish is called Yikes
one of the crew was a very mad science inventor (so it's on the line as far as genre goes)
they had a tree house clubhouse where they would often meet

Apparently it's based on a toy line that's been in and out since the 80s.  There was an 80s tv show too, but the characters aren't the same.

Could this be Rolie Polie Olie, which aired from 1998 to 2004? It features 3D characters, some of whom were able roll around as you describe.

I don't remember nor can find any characters that have polka dots patterns, but they do appear in the show's intro.
Olie's younger sister Zowie wore a pink dress and features in many (all?) episodes.
Olie's family lived in a teapot shaped house, but he and his friends did frequent a treehouse.

